# Troubleshooting 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' error when building Ionic android project with tesseract.js and capacitor core

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have setup ionic angular project and using capacitor to get the native code.

I am using tesseract.js and capacitor core and camera plugins.

But on building the android project I am getting following error:

```
Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)
```

The gradle version I am using is:
       `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'`

I want to use the camera module and take a picture to process it with tesseract.js to get the text from image.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounters this issue.

You need to update your Android Studio to the latest version. Make sure when you open Android Studio that you have the latest version.

In my case, I had, for some reason, two versions of Android Studio and Ionic was opening the old one.

Comment: Quoting the version number may add more clarity to your answer :)

Comment: @rfellons But I said "the latest version"

Comment: But the "latest version" depends on when someone reads your post. In a year, to know what the latest version is, I will have to do a search to know what the latest version was at the date of your post. Better write the version number.